# Terraform module input of `local_file`

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have Terraform module for Azure API management, in `azurerm_api_management` resource `policy` attribute is required.

Value for `policy` attribute must be received from file:

```
data "local_file" "apim_global" {
  filename = "${var.ados_release_dir}/${var.apim_policy_artifact}/api-management/global.xml"
}

module "pau-apim" {
  ...
  policy = {
    xml_content = "${data.local_file.apim_global.content}"
  }
  ...
```

In Terraform module `policy` variable is defined as type of any:

```
variable "policy" {
  type        = any
  description = "A mapping of policy to assign to the apim."
  default     = null
}
```

..but it doesn't work:
[image]

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Can you show the definition of the `azurerm_api_management.api` resource in the module as well? It looks like that's where the error is coming from rather than the module variable.

Answer (score 0):

I was told to use `xml_content` as an input instead of `policy = { xml_content = ..." }`

..and it did the trick

Comment: This answer and question combination would be much more useful for others who might have the same issue if you included a [mcve] in the question and then clearly showed the changes you made to that in your answer that then solved your issue. As it stands this isn't useful to anyone else at all as it's completely opaque and impossible to see what your exact issue was or how you solved it.